# KeyError showing on Pulp program

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have this restriction on a Linear Programming problem:

```
problema += sum(bultos[i]*folioubi.loc[i,j]*x[i][j] for i in folios for j in ubicaciones) == w['Directa']
```

But the program stops here and shows the following error: KeyError: 'Directa'

I'm defining the w variable as the following:

```
w = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Total de bultos por tipo de recolección r',(tiporec),lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
```

Is this correct? It needs to be an Integer variable but I don't know why the key error is showing.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you.  If you are troubleshooting an error, you should put in enough code to reproduce the error.  Your odds of getting help go *way* up.  :).  So, chop out the piece of your program that produces the problem, and just a small slice of the data, and include the corresponding error statement after just running that code segment.  In your code above, `tiporec` is undefined.  You should be able to edit your post with that info.  And after posting code, use the format button to code-format it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.